# Excel - IF a cell contains a value return another value, if not search for a different value

Tags: excel, if-statement

In column A I have a list of domain names with various TLDs e.g. .com .co .net etc.
In Column B I'm wanting to put the annual renewal price.

I know this isn't the correct syntax, but I'm hoping someone could help me.

```
=IF(SEARCH(A2,".com"),9.00,(SEARCH(A2,".net"),10.50,SEARCH(A2,".co.uk"),5.00,"FALSE")
```

Alternatively if there are multiple TLDs with the same value, would it be possible to specify this somehow?

There are several hundred TLDs I'm only wanting to search for a handful, but using VLOOKUP could be away of me adding a comprehensive list of TLDs and being able to search them all.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would fix your function:

```
=IFERROR(IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(".com",A2),FALSE),9,IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(".net",A2),FALSE),10.5,IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(".co.uk",A2),FALSE),5,"NO MATCH"))),"NO MATCH")
```

But the best option would be to use a wildcard lookup function a la barry houdini. There was actually a challenge contest related to this a while ago:

http://www.mrexcel.com/pc18.shtml

Here is an example:

```
=VLOOKUP(LOOKUP(32768,SEARCH(D$2:D$4,A2),D$2:D$4),$D$2:$E$4,2,FALSE)
```

[image: example_image1]

This way you can avoid an infinitely long compound if-statement that checks the innumerable url domain names.

Comment: This seem to work for only the first cell

I've put your formula in but when I drag the handle down it doesn't seem to work as it should

Comment: I Should probably point out this works fine in Excel, but not so fine in Apple Numbers, despite the functions being the same (and available)

Comment: @pnuts Woops. Fixed that.

Comment: @JessicaHoward made the formula consistent with the screenshot. Regarding Apple Numbers, I have never used it - I can't guarantee it will work there.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a lookup table for your TLDs and prices

```
.com | $10
.net | $5
.org | $5
```

Then you want to split your domains so you have the TLD in a separate column.  If all your TLDs are three letters e.g. .net, .com, you can get them into a separate column like this:

```
=RIGHT(A1, 4)
```

If they are not just three letter TLDs, it's a bit more tricky.

Once you split your TLD into a separate column, use the `VLOOKUP` function to look up the price for each TLD.

```
=VLOOKUP(tld_to_lookup, range_of_lookup_table, 2, FALSE)
```

The "2" in that formula is a reference to the second column in your lookup table above and "FALSE" says we don't want an approximate match, we want an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

This array formula will work for finding any arbitrary string within any other arbitrary string:

```
{=VLOOKUP(MID(cellBeingSearched,MIN(IFERROR(FIND(FirstColumnOfTable,A2),1000)),1000),WholeTable,2,FALSE)}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, Where you have added:

cellBeingSearched
FirstColumnOfTable
WholeTable

What tables?

Are yo able to show me an example of your formula as per Stepan101?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The answer @Stepan1010 posted is correct for excel.

It's a form of "array function" (searching a "table array").  Apple Numbers can't do array functions the way Excel can

So for those of you wanting a solution to the issue I was faced with, the following formula works in Both Excel for PC and Mac and Number for Mac.

```
=VLOOKUP(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH(".",A2)+1),C$2:D$4,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: @pnuts Rather than criticise why don't you come up with a solution!